# QGIS Random Points inside a Polygon not creating requested number of points

Tags: qgis

I am trying to create 25 random points in one layer with a minimum of 100m between the points.
after putting the information into the 'random points in polygon' tool it has created 80+ points.
I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong.
[image: Attached is my input parameters]

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the fact that you are not using a projected coordinate system, so your units are in degrees (as the warning sign probably says). Try reprojecting it to some crs using meters, like 27700

Comment: is it a single multipart feature, or do you have several features?